# QGIS2web crashes latest QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis2web, qgis-2.14

Upgraded QGIS to 2.14 (Essen) using OSGeo4W and upgraded all plugins:
QGIS2web > 'create web map' immediately freezes QGIS requiring kill and relaunch.
Here's the python log trace:
016-03-06T15:10:23  1   warning:C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py:844: PendingDeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions.  Use 'elem.iter()' or 'list(elem.iter())' instead.
              for include in elem.getiterator("include"):

```
        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 271, in loadPlugin
            __import__(packageName)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/hogs hollow/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from processing.tools.general import *
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/hogs hollow/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 28, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/hogs hollow/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 42, in <module>
            from processing.gui.MessageBarProgress import MessageBarProgress
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/hogs hollow/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\gui\MessageBarProgress.py", line 34, in <module>
            from processing.gui.MessageDialog import MessageDialog
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/hogs hollow/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\gui\MessageDialog.py", line 38, in <module>
            os.path.join(pluginPath, 'ui', 'DlgMessage.ui'))
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 210, in loadUiType
            winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, code_string, from_imports, resource_suffix)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 139, in compileUi
            w = self.parse(input_stream, resource_suffix)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 933, in parse
            actor(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 844, in readResources
            for include in elem.getiterator("include")
```

Comment: I think that warning in the trace is a red herring, but I'm not sure. Can you try to narrow things down to see if, for instance, the problem is related to one specific layer, and not to others?

Answer (score 1):

I've identified the cause: I'm using an ecw raster as a background map.
If I switch that off qgis2web works, if its active qgis2web QGIS crashes when the 'create web map' is activated.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but that's still a major issue for qgis2web. Difficult for me to investigate - isn't ECW licensed? I've certainly never used them before.

Comment: Raised issue at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/220